# Scrapy is not pulling the live table data, it's only pulling the tables code instead?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from tutorial.items import Table
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class GoalSpider(Spider):
    name = "stats"
    allowed_domains = ["numberfire.com"]
    start_urls = ('http://www.numberfire.com/nba/fantasy/full-fantasy-basketball-projections', )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        items = hxs.xpath('//td/text()')

        with open("stats.txt", 'wb') as f:
            for item in items:
                f.write(item.extract() + ' || ')

        for item in items:
            my_item = Table()
            my_item['tal'] = item.select('.//text()').extract()
            my_item['sep'] = item.select('.//text()').extract()
            yield my_item
```

Hello, ok so the above code is suppose to go to the website and pull the table data, row by row and write it as plain text to a file. Unfortunately I cannot figure out why but, when I use the crawler, the values are just :

```
${opponent.abbrev} || #${opponent_rank} || ${minutes} || ${pts} || ${fgm}-${fga} || ${ftm}-${fta} || ${p3m}-${p3a} || ${treb} || ${ast} || ${stl} || ${blk} || ${tov} || ${pf} || ${fp} || $${salary} || ${ratio} ||
```

I believe I am separating it correctly but I don't understand why the crawler is pulling the table data like this, these are the correct rows and such but its not the actual data itself. It seems as if the data being pulled is the code for the table and not the actual data.

Comment: the parsing is correct, that is the real information on that response body, this is a javascript rendering problem (the data you want is coming from a different request)

Comment: @eLRuLL so is there no possible way of obtaining this data then?

Comment: of course there is (the browser is doing it) you just need to check which is the correct request that comes with this data, use something like firebug (firefox) or just developer console on chrome to check requests. You can also use selenium if you want to emulate a browser.

Comment: I've been digging around but I cant seem to find any help on how to extract this data, I've used firebug to try and search for the request but I did not have any luck. I'm not really sure what I am looking for to be quite honest.

Comment: look in firebug on "Network -> XHR" - `XHR` means `AJAX`

Comment: btw: look for `var NF_DATA=` in file. It seems your data.